# Local Client server Git setup for Xcode projects

Tags: xcode, git

I have a scenario, we are team of 5 iOS developers. Working on iMAC with OSX 10.8 and xCode version 4.5. Now i want to have Git Version control system during working on same Project.
I have read tutorials for Git but all have remote as online server like github.com or bitbucket. I want to create Local network Git server (Most probably my own iMAC) so that we can work on our local network.

Can anybody guide me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  sparkleshare here http://sparkleshare.org/ which uses GIT under the hood.

**How does it work?**

SparkleShare creates a special folder on your computer in which projects are kept. All projects are automatically synced to their respective hosts (you can have multiple projects connected to different hosts) and to your team's SparkleShare folders when someone adds, removes or edits a file.

If you want to install your own private git server i found this useful http://blog.muehlbachler.org/2012/01/how-to-install-a-private-debian-git-server-using-gitolite-and-gitlabhq/

There could be plenty of results if you googled 'git private server'.

I hope that helped a bit.

Edit

There is also gitlab - http://gitlab.org/ which is a self hosted git management software.

Comment: Thanx "Jesus With Issues", can i have my own MAC as Git Server as well as client?
Or can I make one of my windows machine as Git server and use it with my Xcode projects in our iMAC?

Comment: IMHO i think both methods are possible but i am thinking you have to reserve a static ip for the git server if you share the git server with your mates.

Comment: Hi Jesus, i have spent hours in setup private git server on MAC or windows system but no success. Can you please help me

Comment: That wouldn't be entirely feasible since i am a student.You can however look at my updated answer.